# What is the maximum voltage that a RJ9/RJ10/RJ22 can carry?

Tags: voltage, current, maximum-ratings

I want to use a 4p4c modular jack for carrying isoSPI data and 12V at <1.5A and am not sure if the connector or cable could handle that

Comment: you should really be asking about current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you were way off with 1.5 A but a browse through Farnell's list of RJ22 connectors found this.

[image]

*Figure 1. Extract from [MTP-44U -  CAT5 RJ22 MODULAR PLUG, 4 POSITION, 1 PORT](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1647392.pdf?_ga=2.231620890.420209321.1561678282-1249722243.1545817612&_gac=1.59912159.1561580334.CjwKCAjwr8zoBRA0EiwANmvpYP-JUjR82DdxHqOSVDaT0uiqqDPyGr6V574tCeoW3py1B57rEdFkthoC4uYQAvD_BwE).*

The voltage isn't a problem as they have to take telephone ringing voltage which is about 100 V AC. I was surprised at the 1.5 A current rating but be aware that the you'll have to have the same rating on the socket and your conductors will be rather small for that current too.